# IIS 8.5: Problem hosting a 32bit ASP.NET MVC5 website along with a 64bit .netcore2.2 website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

As the title suggests we need to host side-by-side two different websites (each with its own application pool) in IIS 8.5 Windows Server 2012 fully updated.

One site is ASP.NET MVC5 and runs in 32bit mode while the other website is a .netcore2.2 website running in 64bit mode.

The .netcore2.2 needs the AspNetModuleCoreV2.dll to be loaded in IIS. Problem is this causes the 32bit website to crash on load (503 Service Unavailable).

If we remove from ApplicationHost.config the 64bit AspNetModuleCoreV2.dll pointing to:

```
 C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll
 (or even replace it with the 32bit flavor C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll)
```

then the 32bit website works fine but this causes the 64bit .netcore2.2 website to fail.

So how can we make both websites happy under the same roof of IIS8.5? Things we have tried:

Employ a remove-handler tweak in the web.config of the 32bit website:

```
<handlers>
   <remove name="AspNetCoreModule" />
   <remove name="AspNetCoreModuleV2" />
</handlers>
```

This didn't work unfortunately. Still getting 503 (update: Good idea bad execution - read below - we might have goofed on this!)

Update: Hmmm while writing this two things came almost immediately to our minds:

1. To remove a module we should employ the following section in Web.config (instead of < handlers >):

   ```
   < system.webServer >

     < modules >

       < remove name="AspNetCoreModule" />

       < remove name="AspNetCoreModuleV2" />

     < /modules>

   < system.webServer>
   ```
2. For some reason the installer installed the AspNetCoreModuleV2 module as:

   C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll

Instead of:

```
%ProgramFiles%\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll
```

The environment variables is the difference that might make the difference when it comes down to 32bit websites. Going to try things out.

Comment: I guess that they must run on different WebSites and different ApplicationPool.

Comment: I forgot to mention: They are different websites and they do run in different appPools. Thanks for pointing out the need for a clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the culprit was indeed that (for whatever reason) the runtime installer of .netcore2.2 decided to hardcode the path to 'aspnetcorev2.dll' inside ApplicationHost.config of IIS to have it point to C:\Program Files...

As already stated, the correct way to register the module is:

```
   %ProgramFiles%\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll
```

This way when a website is running in 32bit mode it will load the correct flavour of the dll from:

```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll
```

And everything will work from that point on.

If you want to play it extra-safe when deploying to client-servers which are out of your control you may want to additionally explicitly remove any and all 'aspnetcorev2' modules in the Web.config of your 32bit ASP.NET MVC5 like so:

```
      < system.webServer >

        < modules >

          < remove name="AspNetCoreModule" />

          < remove name="AspNetCoreModuleV2" />

        < /modules>

      < system.webServer>
```